# Find messages without a label in GMail/ undo Remove Label

Tags: email, gmail, undo, label

I was organising messages in my GMail account, I had a few messages selected (whilst in a sub-folder) and I accidentally clicked `Remove Label` and now they are gone!

Now I know they are still somewhere in my account but I just can't find them.

Is there any way of getting them back?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! Use

```
has:nouserlabels
```

in your search field. Google has a help page for that: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en

You'll probably see labeled messages as well, refer to the note on the bottom.

> Messages that have or don't have a label
>   has:userlabels
>
> has:nouserlabels
>
> Example: has:nouserlabels
>
> **Note:** Labels are only added to a message, and not an entire conversation.